# Why does canvas draw lines between circle (arc)?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, canvas

In the moment canvas draw 15 circles with different speed and size which move from ltr. when one of them leaves the window it will be set to the start. The Problem is that canvas draw lines between the circles and i dont know why? Can anybody help?

```
window.onload = function () {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var W = canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    var H = canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    var mp = 15; //max particles
    var particles = [];
    //var rotate = 180;

    reqAnimFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame ||
                   window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
                   window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
                   window.msRequestAnimationFrame     ||
                   window.oRequestAnimationFrame;

    for ( var i = 0; i < mp; i++ )
        {
            particles.push({
                x: Math.floor(Math.random()*W), //x-coordinate
                y: Math.floor(Math.random()*H), //y-coordinate
                d: Math.floor(Math.random()*(mp - 1) + 1), //density
                r: Math.floor(Math.random()*(70 - 10) + 10) //radius
            })
        }



    function animate() {
        reqAnimFrame(animate);
        for ( var i = 0; i < mp; i++ )
            {
                var p = particles[i];
                p.x += p.d;


                if(p.x >= W){
                    p.x = -300;
                    p.y = Math.floor(Math.random()*H);
                }
                draw();
            }
    }

    function draw() {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);
        ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,204,142,1";
        ctx.beginPath();
        for ( var i = 0; i < mp; i++ )
            {
                var p = particles[i];
                ctx.arc(p.x, p.y, p.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
                //ctx.moveTo(p.x,p.y);
                //ctx.lineTo(p.x + 150, p.y + (-180));
                //ctx.lineTo(p.x + 300, p.y);
            }
        ctx.stroke();
    }
    animate();
    };//onload function
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change the code a little bit as `beginPath()` and `stroke()` are now only called once - what happens is that the arcs are accumulated in the loop and since they are not really circles - they have two open ends - these ends will be connected to each other creating lines between the arcs.

Try the following:

```
function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,204,142,1";
    for ( var i = 0; i < mp; i++ ) {
        var p = particles[i];
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(p.x, p.y, p.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
        ctx.stroke();
    }
}
```